# how to join 3 nodes in Windows RabbitMQ cluster

Tags: rabbitmq

I am configuring RabbitMQ cluster in windows. i am able to create 2node cluster. when i am trying to add 3rd node, the 2nd is missing ( it is replacing 2nd node ) and able to see newly added node only in place of previously added node.
In brief....
Server1 taken as main server.
Server2 added to Server1 and now i can see Server1&Server2 as a cluster in overview. 
When adding server3 to server1, it is replacing server2 and now i can see only server1&server3 in overview.

So i tried to add server3 to server2 and now it is showing 3 servers as node but it showing the error as below.

"Network partition detected

Mnesia reports that this RabbitMQ cluster has experienced a network partition. There is a risk of losing data."

Please suggest. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWlt5.png)